# Erro Estanho console Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Estava desenvolvendo um sistema onde atualizei uma página e começou a apresentar um erro estranho no console do Google Chrome, o que pode ser? Como resolver?

> Font from origin 'http://error.hostinger.eu' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   Origin 'http://www.meusite.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode estar apontando alguma fonte externa de um link hostinger bloqueado! Tente acessar o site que está tentando se conectar ao hotlink e veja se tem algo de errado! Este link, costuma aparecer quando o site foi bloqueado por excesso de visitas, isso acaba sobrecarregando o sistema!

Comment: ok, Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: de nada, tamo aqui pra isso!

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando fazer hotlink nesse endereço 'http://error.hostinger.eu' e não está habilitado para isso.

Tente remover qualquer conexão / link externo para hostinger e veja se o erro some.

Comment: ok, Obrigado pela ajuda.